# Consultar nombres desde C# a SQL

Tags: c#

Hola a todos estoy realizando una consulta en SQL desde C# con procedimientos ya tengo todo pero en el botón consultar no se como hacer para llenar el datagrid con la consulta estoy utilizando windows forms que pida mi código es así.

```
    public static string ConsultarDatos(string nombres)
    {
        string comprador;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(TraerCadena("Comprador.Properties.Settings.NotasConnectionString")))
        {

            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("ConsultarName"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres",nombres);


                comprador = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        return comprador;
    }
```

// este es mi boton pero nose como hago para que despues de cumplir el procedimiento hacia la clase llenar el data grid con la consulta

```
 private void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Procedimiento.ConsultarDatos(txt_Comprador.Text);

    }
```

Comment: Hola, estás utilizando Windows Forms?. Si es así indícalo en le pregunta.

Comment: Hola, si estoy usando forms ya edite la pregunta y lo agregue gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a mostrar los datos en un grid deberias devolver los datos en una lista o datatable

```
public static DataTable ConsultarDatos(string nombres)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(TraerCadena("Comprador.Properties.Settings.NotasConnectionString")))
    {

        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("ConsultarName"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres",nombres);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

entonces lo usas

```
private void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = Procedimiento.ConsultarDatos(txt_Comprador.Text);

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: También es aceptable ver todas y aprender varias maneras

Comment: Muchas gracias leandro solucionaste mi problema